# Android filename with white space cannot be opened

Tags: android, whitespace, filenames

My code works correctly while opening a file in sdcard. However, if I open a filename with white space then error occurs (example: Path - "/sdcard/download/hello hi.jpg").

I tried string.replace(" ","%20"); it doesn't work

```
try {
    File file = new File(paths);
    if (file.exists()) {
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(paths));

        if (!mimeType.equals("")) {
            intent.setDataAndType(path, mimeType);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unsupported Format to Open", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No Application Available to View this File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch(Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error Occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Please help

Comment: What is the error that occurs? Paste any relevant logs.

Comment: No Error is coming. Exception thrown has no message.

Comment: Every Exception will have a stack trace. It's not shown because you're catching all Exceptions and discarding valuable information. Insert this in the catch blocks: Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);

Comment: Paste the stacktrace printed in logcat.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at oystor.app.Document.imglist.viewDocument(imglist.java:906)
     at oystor.app.Document.imglist.viewDoc(imglist.java:773)
     at oystor.app.Document.imglist$OrderAdapter$1.onClick(imglist.java:318)

Comment: Is there any valid answer for this question?

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(paths);
File file = new File(uri.getPath());
```

`Uri.parse` fixes all the whitespace/backslash/illegal character issues in paths and produces a "good" uri.

Comment: Thanks mr obvious :D No seriously, you helped me out.

Comment: Uri.parse() doesn't remove spaces in my case.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the spaces.  Try replacing " " with "\ "

Comment: Syntax error occurs. Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: `"foo bar".replace(" ", "\\ ");`

Answer (score 1):

Replace **%20** with space like below

```
filePath =  filePath.replaceAll("%20"," ");
```

This worked for me