# Display images stored on sd card on gridview

Tags: android

I have images stored on sd card.

Here is the path.

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/2014-04-06%2010%3A49%3A20.jpg
```

These images paths are stored in sqlite db. i have a method that returns these paths as a list.

I have made a layout file with a gridview for the activity that dispalys the images.
I have also made layout file with an image view widget . i want to create a baseadapter to inflate this layout file.
here lay out main activity.

<

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"  
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"  
    >

</GridView>
```

Here is the layout for baseadapter layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>



</LinearLayout
```

Below is the code for the main images activity

```
public class ImagesActivity extends Activity {
   private ImagesAdapter adapter;
   List<Incidentmages> images= new ArrayList<Incidentmages>();
   DBHelperClass db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        db= new DBHelperClass(this);        
        setContentView(R.layout.incident_images);
        Intent i=getIntent();
        String myid=i.getStringExtra("IncidentID");
        Log.e("id", myid);
        int _id= Integer.parseInt(myid);
        // get image paths in a list
        images=db.GetIncidentImages(_id);
        adapter= new ImagesAdapter(this,R.layout.images_display,images);

         GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

            // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          db.close();
            super.onStop();
        }
    @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         db.close();
            super.onPause();
        }
    @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.close();
            super.onDestroy();
        }
}
```

Here is the code for the baseadapter

```
public class ImagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context1;
    int layoutid;
    List<Incidentmages> images= new ArrayList<Incidentmages>();
    public ImagesAdapter(Context context, int resourcelayouteid,
             List<Incidentmages> images 
            ) {

        this.context1=context;
        this.layoutid=resourcelayouteid;
        this.images=images;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return images.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = view;
          RecordHolder holder = null;

          if (row == null) {
              LayoutInflater inflater=
                        LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
                      row =inflater.inflate(layoutid,parent,false);

           holder = new RecordHolder();
           holder.imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
           row.setTag(holder);
          } else {
           holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();          }

          Incidentmages d= (Incidentmages)images.get(position);
            String path= d.getPath();
            String mypath= path.substring(5,path.length());
            String FKID= Integer.toString(d.getIncident_id());
            Log.e("Imageadapter", path);    
            Log.e("FK",FKID);
            Bitmap bm= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mypath);
          holder.imageItem.setImageBitmap(bm);

          return row;

         }

         static class RecordHolder {
         ImageView imageItem;

         }











}
```

You can see that i use BitmapFactory to set image bitmaps....

The strings i get looks like

```
///mnt/sdcard/2014-04-06%2010%3A49%3A20.jpg
```

Now the problem is that the images don't display. I get a blank screen.

Anything wrong with my code?

Perhaps the prolem is the way i get the path?

Below is how i get the path string from the URI

```
  {
SimpleDateFormat fm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
            Date mydate = new Date();
            String imagenumber= fm.format(mydate) + ".jpg";
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    imagenumber);
                    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent picintent= new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            picintent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(picintent,TAKE_PHOTO);   
            myPaths.add(outputFileUri.toString());

        }
```

Comment: any error you might want to add that you get ?

Comment: I dont get errors. I have debugged and noticed that all variables are correctly populated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the spaces. Try replacing " " with "\ "

```
mypath.replace("%20", "\\ ");
```

EDIT : There should be two backslashes in the second arg here. One got consumed in the markdown. I have corrected it.

Try, this should probably work.

EDIT: You have `%3A` in your filepath. Not sure, replace them with `=` and your image path should work.

```
mypath.replace("%3A","=")
```

Referenced from another SO question about [filenames with whitespaces in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765384/android-filename-with-white-space-cannot-be-opened)

Comment: tried it and got ///mnt/sdcard/2014-04-06\2010\3A49\3A33.jpg
and it is not opeing the image too

Comment: I have edited my answer. Is the file name in your SD card is like `2014-04-06 10=49=20` or `2014-04-06 10-49-20` ?

Comment: hello..have you seen my edit in the main thread on how i get the file path? may be wrong?

Comment: so you don't get the path from the database anymore ?

Comment: checking them on sd they appear like IMG_20140406_161206.jpg

Comment: I store that string i get as photo path in the db!

Comment: Do one quick and dirty trick, hard-code one image path, `IMG_20140406_161206.jpg` and see if you get that particular image for all the list items or not

Comment: I done and i dont get too...it seems i am on the wrong track!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with way i was saving the path!...

I have added the code to get the file path  when an image is captured.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent resultData) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);

            if (resultData != null) {

            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            projection, null, null, null);
                    int column_index_data = cursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                    cursor.moveToLast();

                    String imagePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
                    // add image path
                   myPaths.add(imagePath);
            }
```