# "java.io.FileNotFoundException (No such file or directory)"

Tags: android, file, android-intent, android-permissions

I have a class in my project to upload an image and save in my database and if successful, save it locally. This works and I am able to save the the image in a custom folder I created on my android phone.

However, in another class, I'm trying to download an encoded image in text form and save it locally using the method i used above but it doesn't work anymore. It seems I can't create the folder.

I don't understand how it worked on my other class and not in this

I tried checking my manifest file and see if I included the needed permissions and if they are in the right places

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="buenaventura.dorothy.tbmgmtapp">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/lungs"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        tools:replace="android:icon">
...
```

[EDIT] Ok, I tried removing the whitespace in my filepath to check if the whitespace was really what was causing the problem and it still didn't work

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + File.separator + "TBSystem" + File.separator + patient_id + File.separator + "lab_result_" + sqlDateToString(result_date) + ".jpg");
```

Also, how come it works on my other class with the whitespace and not on this one? :(

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + File.separator + "TB System" + File.separator + patient_id);

if (!folder.exists()) {
    folder.mkdirs();
}

folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + File.separator + "TB System" + File.separator + patient_id + File.separator + "lab_result_" + result_date + ".jpg");

byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(encoded_image, 0);
Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);

try (
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(folder)) {
    imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out); 
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/TB System/pat1/lab_result_2019-04-06.jpg (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:308)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:238)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:180)
        at buenaventura.dorothy.tbmgmtapp.db_volley.VolleyDownloadRequest$1.onResponse(VolleyDownloadRequest.java:569)
        at buenaventura.dorothy.tbmgmtapp.db_volley.VolleyDownloadRequest$1.onResponse(VolleyDownloadRequest.java:103)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

patient_id and result_date are just strings. encoded_image is a lontext

I need to be able to convert the encoded text I downloaded to bitmap and save it in the custom folder 'TB System' I expect to find inside DCIM. Another folder should be created inside TB System (i.e pat1, pat2, pat3, ...) and the images will be saved inside these.

Answer (score 0):

I see the path you use contains a space between "TB" and "System", this might cause problems. Does your other class also contain filepaths with spaces? If it does not, this might be the issue.

Check out this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765384/android-filename-with-white-space-cannot-be-opened) that helps when dealing with spaces in filepaths. The answer never got approved, so I'm not sure if actually solved the issue but they mention this snippet of code:

```java
Uri uri = Uri.parse(paths);
File file = new File(uri.getPath());
```

> Uri.parse fixes all the whitespace/backslash/illegal character issues
>   in paths and produces a "good" uri.

Comment: Yes, my other class also contain filepaths with spaces too. It works, though.

Comment: Well, you can't just remove the space like that - if the folder is called TB System, hten it is normal for your code to give a fileNotFound exception if you try to access TBSystem. Because you mention the other class does work, perhaps post that class and the output of the code for that class as well so we can compare the two classes?

Comment: I am actually trying to make the directory if it does not already exist. The class that works basically uses the exact method. Initially, the directory does not exist and when the user uploads an image, the app then creates a local directory in my android phone

Comment: @dorothyanne I have updated the solution, let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you check the Read and write permission.

READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE must be check-in programmatically

Use this

```
    private boolean checkPermission(){
      if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != 
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != 
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If true do your work

If false call this method

```
private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1001;

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        }, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And add this code

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == 
             PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                //Do your work
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: can i do this too inside volley request?

Comment: It will be your project have a splash page. This method call at splash page. Only call at first play.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your code, i have tested the combinations with Space in folder & also with exact file name it is working. Working code snippet based on your problem is as below,

Image Downloaded Successfully Snapshot

[image]

Code Layout View

[image]

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zackdawood.albummanager"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">AlbumManager</string>
    <string name="write_button">Write Image</string>
    <string name="read_button">Read Image</string>
    <string name="request_access">Request Access</string>
</resources>
```

external_files.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">maven.apache.org</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">upload.wikimedia.org</domain>
</domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

GenericFileProvider.java

```
package com.zackdawood.albummanager;

import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;

public class GenericFileProvider extends FileProvider {
}
```

FileDownloader.java

```
package com.zackdawood.albummanager;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class FileDownloader {

    private static final String TAG = "FileDownloader";

    private static final int MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

    public static void downloadFile(String fileUrl, File directory) {
        try {
            Log.v(TAG, "downloadFile() invoked ");
            Log.v(TAG, "downloadFile() fileUrl " + fileUrl);
            Log.v(TAG, "downloadFile() directory " + directory);

            URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(directory);
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[MEGABYTE];
            int bufferLength = 0;
            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }
            fileOutputStream.close();
            Log.v(TAG, "downloadFile() completed ");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "downloadFile() error" + e.getMessage());
            Log.e(TAG, "downloadFile() error" + e.getStackTrace());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "downloadFile() error" + e.getMessage());
            Log.e(TAG, "downloadFile() error" + e.getStackTrace());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "downloadFile() error" + e.getMessage());
            Log.e(TAG, "downloadFile() error" + e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.zackdawood.albummanager;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET};

    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS, 112);
        Log.v(TAG, "onCreate() Method invoked ");
    }

    public void write(View view) {
        if (!hasPermissions(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS)) {

            Log.v(TAG, "download() Method DON'T HAVE PERMISSIONS ");

            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You don't have write access !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();

        } else {

            new DownloadFile().execute("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/Adler.jpg/547px-Adler.jpg", "lab_result_2019-04-06.jpg");


        }
    }

    public void read(View view) {
        if (!hasPermissions(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS)) {

            Log.v(TAG, "download() Method DON'T HAVE PERMISSIONS ");

            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You don't have read access !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();

        } else {

            File folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

            File directory = new File(folder + "/TB System");
            File imgFile = new File(directory, "lab_result_2019-04-06.jpg");

            Log.v(TAG, "view() Method imgfile " + imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

            Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", imgFile);


            Log.v(TAG, "view() Method path " + path);

            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            imageIntent.setDataAndType(path, "image/*");
            imageIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            imageIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

            try {
                startActivity(imageIntent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Application available to view Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }

    public void request(View view) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS, 112);

    }

    private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Log.v(TAG, "doInBackground() Method invoked ");

            String fileUrl = strings[0];   // -> http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/maven.pdf
            String fileName = strings[1];  // -> maven.pdf
            File folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

            File directory = new File(folder + "/TB System");
            if (!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdir();
                Log.v(TAG, "doInBackground() Method Directory Created ");

            }

            File imgFile = new File(directory, fileName);
            Log.v(TAG, "doInBackground() imgFile invoked " + imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            Log.v(TAG, "doInBackground() imgFile invoked " + imgFile.getAbsoluteFile());

            try {
                imgFile.createNewFile();
                Log.v(TAG, "doInBackground() file created" + imgFile);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground() error" + e.getMessage());
                Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground() error" + e.getStackTrace());


            }
            FileDownloader.downloadFile(fileUrl, imgFile);
            Log.v(TAG, "doInBackground() file download completed");

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="715dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/write_button"
            android:onClick="write"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/read_button"
            android:onClick="read"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/request_access"
            android:onClick="request"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zackdawood.albummanager">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
        <provider
            android:name=".GenericFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/external_files"/>
        </provider>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

App Launcher Screen

[image]

Read Image Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

before accessing or writing to a file, create its parent and the file itself, to be on safe side.
in this case... just before try catch block, or at least before FileOutputStream line, create the file by `if (!folder.exists()) folder.createNewFile();`

you're need Storage permission (READ-WRITE EXTERNAL STORAGE) to create a file outside app's data directory

this might help